# proximity search in apache solr

Tags: drupal-6, solr

Hi I m using apachesolr with drupal 6

I need to implement proximity search
can anyone suggest me the sample sites using apache solr proximity search so that i can get idea in terms of interface/page UI perspective and functionality

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Solr provides an easy syntax for proximity searches.

you would need to use the `~` operator followed by the `number of positions` the words need to be apart.

The number of positions is decided by how many moves it would take to physically move the words to create the exact sequence being searched for.

If you want to search for words internet banking within a proximity of 10 positions, the query can be as

```
q="internet banking"~10
```

Brief info @ 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_search_for_one_term_near_another_term_.28say.2C_.22batman.22_and_.22movie.22.29

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Proximity%20Searches

Dismax did not support the fuzzy searches @ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-629

You may want to check the current state of support.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, I need the websites in which proximity search has implemented so that i can take idea for creating search form UI. when i enter "continuous Challenges"~1 in my search page textfield it is giving me the results with the tiles have 1

Comment: Are you using Standard request handler or dismax/edismax, as fuzzy searches were not supported by dismax. You may want to check it further.

Comment: Sorry for late reply i m using dismax request handler

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-629 dismax didn't support fuzzy searches. I dont think edismax supports as well. you may want to check on this further.